# PHP 5.6.11 tokenizer is missing

Tags: php, composer-php

When running `composer install` I get the following error:

```
- phpunit/php-token-stream 1.4.8 requires ext-tokenizer * -> the requested PHP extension tokenizer is missing from your system.
```

I am using PHP `5.6.11`.

Comment: Where's the image?

Comment: I thought it was uploaded, but i dont have the permissions yet. So I created a link now. Thnx for the notice

Comment: Can you run `php -v` and also give us your php version?

Comment: Tokenizer is supposed to be enabled by default from PHP 4.3 and above. Try running `php -m | grep tokenizer`

Comment: php version is 5.6.11, add the link in first message

Comment: I have tried grep tokenizerbut nothing happened [https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B99XVIVJbVa7d2pTQVNlTkl1c2s] @theomessin

Comment: So you ran `php -m | grep tokenizer` and nothing returned, right? This means that for some reason your `php` doesn't have tokenizer installed. If I were you I'd reinstall `php` (and install PHP 7).

Comment: ok, thanks for the quick response

Comment: I have found out that synology DSM6 has to different php. 
So I ran `php56 -m | grep tokenizer` and get the answer tokenizer

Answer (score 0):

If any extension is missing, it can be enabled by linking the appropriate ini file from `/etc/php/mods-available`.

The path varies from system to system and mostly depends on the version of the PHP used.

I was able to link the tokenizer extension by issuing this command

`/etc/php/<Version-Number>/cli/conf.d$ sudo ln -s ../../mods-available/tokenizer.ini 20-tokenzer.ini`